# Condition number of a matrix with factorization $A=QR$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=QR$ when $Q$ is orthogonal and R is triangular superior proof $\dfrac{1}{n}k_1(A)\leq k_1(R) \leq n k_1(A) $ and $k_2(A)=k_2(R)$

So we have for the second part $k_2(A)=||A||_2|||A^{-1}||_2$ and we know $||A||_2=||QR||_2=||R||_2$ and $||A^{−1}||_2=||R^{-1}Q^t||_2=||R^{−1}||_2$ then $k_2(A)=k_2(R)$.

For the first part, I don't know how to do it someone can help me and for the second part is my proof correct? Ty all and sorry for the mistakes I'm new in numerical analysis.

Comment: Note that $\|A\|_1 \le \sqrt{n} \|A\|_2$ and $\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt{n} \|A\|_1$. Combine this with the second result to get the first.

Comment: I see that thx.